# Python (Jupyter) "equals" assignment is creating changes in RHS variable downstream

Tags: python, python-2.7, equals-operator

I am trying the following code in Python, using Jupyter Notebooks:

```
import numpy as np

i=2
j=0

basis = np.matrix([False,False,True,True,True])
basis_mod = basis
print "basis"
print basis
print "basis_mod"
print basis_mod

basis_mod[:,i] = False
print "basis"
print basis
print "basis_mod"
print basis_mod

basis_mod[:,j] = True
print "basis"
print basis
print "basis_mod"
print basis_mod
```

The console output / what's printed is:

```
basis
[[False False  True  True  True]]
basis_mod
[[False False  True  True  True]]
basis
[[False False False  True  True]]
basis_mod
[[False False False  True  True]]
basis
[[ True False False  True  True]]
basis_mod
[[ True False False  True  True]]
```

My question is: Why is the variable basis being changed, when I'm making modifications to basis_modified? To be clear, I am modifying the basis_mod variable, so I'd expect the basis variable not to change. However, when I print the basis variable, it is changing to be equal to the basis_mod variable.

Note that, if I change the code to:

```
import numpy as np

i=2
j=0

basis = np.matrix([False,False,True,True,True])
basis_mod = np.matrix([False,False,True,True,True])
print "basis"
print basis
print "basis_mod"
print basis_mod

basis_mod[:,i] = False
print "basis"
print basis
print "basis_mod"
print basis_mod

basis_mod[:,j] = True
print "basis"
print basis
print "basis_mod"
print basis_mod
```

The print-out is as expected:

```
basis
[[False False  True  True  True]]
basis_mod
[[False False  True  True  True]]
basis
[[False False  True  True  True]]
basis_mod
[[False False False  True  True]]
basis
[[False False  True  True  True]]
basis_mod
[[ True False False  True  True]]
```

Therefore, I suspect the issue is with the line basis_mod = basis, but I don't understand why.

Any help is greatly appreciated! This is majorly messing up an algorithm I'm trying to code.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with arrays or lists, (any mutable data structure in this regard), you are actually storing the reference to that variable.

If you want your `basis` unchanged, you need to create a copy of `basis` and store it in `basis_mod`.

```
>>> import numpy

>>> basis = numpy.matrix([1, 2])
>>> basis_mod = basis
>>> basis_mod[0] = [3, 4]

>>> basis
matrix([[3, 4]])
>>> basis_mod
matrix([[3, 4]])

>>> basis_mod = basis.copy()
>>> basis_mod[0] = [5, 6]
>>> basis
matrix([[3, 4]])
>>> basis_mod
matrix([[5, 6]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I added to the top of my code: "import copy" and changed "basis_mod = basis" to "basis_mod = copy.deepcopy(basis)" and it worked. I think "basis_mod = copy.copy(basis)" or "basis_mod = basis.copy()" would have also worked.

Comment: @AparnaAnanthasubramaniam Correct, `copy.deepcopy` also copies the lists inside that list, so references are replaced with copies.

Answer (score 0):

In python when you are writing `a=b` then you are actually referencing variable b to variable a and if u make changes to any of variables then those changes will automatically be applied to another variable. Actually they will become identical with different names

```
a is b will output True
```